# Check if UIAlertController action sheet is dismissed through cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

I have implemented action sheet though alert controller. I want to display a button like cancel button with "Pay" Text written on it.

Issue is `makeCall()` function call when pay button is clicked , And when rest of the screen is tapped `makeCall()` function is called again.

How can I identify that action is called through pay button action or through Tapp on rest of the screen? I only want to make call to `makeCall()` function when pay button is tapped.

```
alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)    

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Pay", style: .cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in
    printLog("cancelAction")
    makeCall()
}

cancelAction.isEnabled = false
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

self.present(alertController, animated: true) {}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to set Pay to a cancel action? Why don't you add one more button for your Pay action?

Comment: I have to make UI like this? How can I make button look like this? I want look and filed like cancel button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, alert controller view userInteraction disable so when tap outside alert controller not close.

**You can do like this:**

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true){
    if let mainView = alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0]{
           mainView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
     }
}
```

**OR**

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
   if let allContainerView = alertController.view.superview?.subviews{
       for myview in allContainerView{
           if (myview.gestureRecognizers != nil){
                 myview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: It works , is it optimum solution? As getting the subview at index 0. Means views stack hierarchy can be changed in future.

Comment: @HimanDhawan good question, Yes,It's optimum solution. This Views stack hierarchy can be changed in future but is major changed so it might less chance to happen. I have update my answer other solution for your concern.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer , great work Nimesh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any solution that how can you identify that action is called through pay button action or through Tap on rest of the screen.

but the alter solution is that you `add tap gesture on rest view`. So, you can identify that if cancel button tap or tap in rest of the screen.

```
alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Pay", style: .cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in
                printLog("cancelAction")
                makeCall()
            }

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
                let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissAlertController))
                alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            }


@objc func dismissAlertController(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("through Tap on rest of the screen")
    }
```